# Using screenshot_and_open_image method from capybara-screenshot gem; I want to be able to specify what file name to save by

Tags: ruby, selenium, automation, capybara, screenshot

So in my spec,  I'm using the screenshot_and_open_image from from capybara-screenshot gem to capture image, however I want to also be able to tell the screenshot_and_open_image method what file name to save the screenshot by, and also not have it open the image afterwards. How can I do that ? If not possible with this gem, are there recommendations for other screenshot gems I can use to achieve this?

When reviewing https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot it was not very clear to me how I can do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the capybara-screenshot gem for that, just use Capybaras `save_screenshot` - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Session#save_screenshot-instance_method

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but if I use Capybara’s save_screenshot, can I pass on an argument with a custom file name to save the screen shot by? I could not find anything about that in the doc.

Comment: @SyedAbbas The first parameter passed to `save_screenshot` is either the relative (to Capybara.save_path) or absolute location of where to save the image - `save_screenshot('blah/image.png')` - relative to Capybara.save_path - `save_screenshot('/blah/image.png')` - absolute location

Comment: @SyedAbbas You're welcome - don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so the question gets marked as answered